# Error in sending a post request using Rest Client , Express and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

```
const express = require('express')
const routing = express.Router()
const flightMethods = require("../model/users")
//implement routing as per the given requirement
routing.post('/bookFlight', (req, res, err, next) => {
    flightBookingObj = JSON.parse(req.body);
    flightMethods.bookFlight(flightBookingObj).then((id) => {
       return res.status(201).json({"message": `Flight booking is successful with booking id ${id}`})
    })
    if(err){
       return next(err);
    }

})
module.exports = routing;
```

Router.js File 
Is this the correct way to pass a json data with Rest client, which sends an object of application/json type.

```
{"customerId": "P1001",
"bookingId": 2001,
 "noOfTickets": 3,
 "bookingCost": 1800,
 "flightId":undefined
 }
```

FlightBookingObj is defined as

```
class FlightBooking {
    constructor(obj) {
        this.customerId = obj.customerId;
        this.bookingId = obj.bookingId;
        this.noOfTickets = obj.noOfTickets;
        this.bookingCost = obj.bookingCost;
        this.flightId = obj.flightId;
    }
}
```

POST request to this route gives an error on the REST Client.

Comment: And how does the error look like?.... Post the error msg!

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /bookFlight</pre>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code to handle Post requests in NodeJs with Express

main.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const routing = require('./routes.js');
    const app = express();
    app.use('/', routing);
    var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    });
```

routes.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    var routing = express.Router();
    routing.route('/bookFlight').post(function(req, res, next)
    {
      var flightBookingObj = req.body.flight; 
      // Assuming your post request has an object called flight in its body

    });
    module.exports = routing;
```